# Install LabelImg Windows

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I tried to install LabelImg after the steps on the site (https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg). I already have installed PyQt4 and lxml. But when I run this command:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

I get this error:

> C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\labelImg-1.7.0>pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc 'pyrcc4' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Trying using pip I get this error:

> C:\Users\Christian>pip install labelImg
>   Collecting labelImg
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/5d/4b8a6dc5e352543199bc3991785af2e1cd58e50f1016e3725db826e3f4bb/labelImg-1.7.0.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ifgpd1gr\labelImg\setup.py", line 8, in 
>           readme = readme_file.read()
>         File "c:\users\christian\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
>           return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 7235: character maps to 
>       ----------------------------------------
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ifgpd1gr\labelImg\

I want to install it without the prebuild binaries because I want to modify labelImg so that it keeps the annotations of the previous pictures, like this: https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/issues/118

Thank you for any hint!

**Edit**: (After adding pyrcc4 to my PATH variable)

```
C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\labelImg-1.7.0>pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\labelImg-1.7.0>python labelImg.py
```

Now I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "labelImg.py", line 29, in 
>       import resources
>     File "C:\Users\Christian\Desktop\labelImg-1.7.0\resources.py", line 9, in 
>       from PyQt4 import QtCore
>   ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

Comment: You should check that executable pyrcc4 is in your search path. Look at echo %PATH%. if not append your PATH env variable to include the directory containing pyrcc4

Comment: I'm really mad at me as I added it as a new variable and not as a PATH variable. Thank you!
Unfortunately, now I get a ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

Answer (score 2):

**Install Python3 via** 
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-357/
**Install PyQt5 and lxml via PIP using below command** 
 `pip3 install pyqt5 lxml`

```
**Download, unzip and run the LabelImg.exe file via**
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kqoxr10l3rkstqd/windows_v1.8.0.zip?dl=1